# rostopic pub - {stamp:now} vs --rate

Tags: rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like publish a continuous flow messages on a topic from the terminal.
In order to do that I use the --rate argument of the rostopic tool. However my message type contains a header field that I would like to fill automatically.

The ros documentation says that you can fill the header stamp automatically ([ref](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/YAMLCommandLine)) in this way:

> $ rostopic pub my_topic my_msgs/StampedMsg '{header: auto}'

However, it looks that the timestamp field does not update when it is used with the --rate parameter. Instead it remains constant with the stamp of the first message of the flow.

> $ rostopic pub my_topic my_msgs/StampedMsg '{header: auto}' --rate 5

Is there any way to use rostopic so that the stamp field is automatically filled and dynamically updated?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232974/rostopic-pub---%7Bstamp:now%7D-vs---rate/) by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2982 on 2016-04-26

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the link '[ros_comm#55](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/55)' of the post of Martin, there is the solution.

Add -s option in the rostopic pub command line.

```
rostopic pub my_topic my_msgs/StampedMsg '{header: auto}' --rate 5 -s
```

---

Originally posted by [bigbellmercy](https://answers.ros.org/users/40244/bigbellmercy/) with karma: 86 on 2019-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, that's a bug in rostopic that I reported about 5 years ago: [ros_comm#55](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/55). So the best workaround is probably to just write a 5-line python script that does the publishing.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2016-04-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1